# How to create a new variable based on group values?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I'm working with some survey data and I am trying to create a new variable "population" that is the number of people within a group (more specifically sex and race). I have been able to create a new dataframe with that information, but I am unable to assign these values back to the original data.

I have tried the following code:

```
#create new dataframe with population by groups
population <- age_data %>% group_by(RACE, SEX) %>% summarise(count = n())

#create new variable with the count
age_data$population <- ifelse(population$RACE== age_data$RACE& population$SEX == age_data$SEX, population$count, NA)
```

I've also tried similar language with `case_when()` and base syntax but I'll get some variation of the following output:

```
Error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Can't recycle `..1` (size 24) to match `..2` (size 169588).
Backtrace:
 1. base::ifelse(...)
 5. vctrs::stop_incompatible_size(...)
 6. vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
 7. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
```

I think I understand that the issue is that there are only 24 categories about which I've created these values, but I can't figure out a way around this.

Here is example (simplified) data:

```
SEX     RACE
1       1
2       3        
1       1
1       2
2       3
2       1
1       3
```

What I would like is this:

```
SEX     RACE     POPULATION
1       1        2
2       3        2
1       1        2
1       2        1
2       1        1
2       3        2
1       3        1
```

I could feasibly just manually print and assign the population values but I am sure there is a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: replace ```summarise``` with ```mutate```

Comment: `summarize` condenses data to one row per group. `mutate` adds columns to the existing data.

Comment: You can also use the dedicated helper function for this common case, `add_count`. `add_count(age_data, RACE, SEX, name = "count")`

Comment: Hi all! Sorry for the later response. I tried changing the summarise to mutate, but now data$population is a tibble rather than a variable, so I can't use it in graphs, etc. Any ideas?

Comment: @GregorThomas the add_count function worked great - I was just curious about the tibble stuff I ran into. Thank you!